# HOw can i access Last record's previous record im mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like,

```
 contractId date          value    
  1          09/02/2011     A         
  2          13/02/2011     C          
  4          02/02/2011     D   
  6          08/02/2011     A  
  7          12/02/2011     C  
  9          22/01/2011     C
```

How can I access the last record'th(9) previous record(contractId - 7)?. Is there any SQL query available?.

Comment: unclear question?? which one you want to retrieve??

Comment: I want below one record

7          12/02/2011     C 

which is previous record for last record

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
ORDER BY contractId DESC
   LIMIT 1,1
```

This query reverses your table and gets one record from the position 1 (so it will be the second row; 0 is the first one).

Comment: only apply to this table, not a valid answer

Comment: So it has to be able to apply to any other ? It works with `Ravichandran`'s table and if he need to apply to something else, he will know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot sort it by date or contractId  you can use something like this:

```
$num = .... SELECT count(*) from contract_table  // get the number of rows.

SELECT * from contract_table LIMIT ($num-1), 1
```